# Gmail logout session

Tags: codeigniter, session, gmail, session-variables, google-signin

If I am currently on my computer logged in via gmail and then login via your application, your app makes the connection between my gmail account and the account of your website.

If I logout, only my session on your website is destroyed and I am logged out from your website. This has no impact on my logged in status on gmail. If I visit the gmail website now, I will still be logged in via my gmail account. Therefore, if I again visit your website and login via gmail, I will be logged in with my associated account.

So if another person wants to login, I first have to go to gmail and logout. The other person has to login on gmail and can then login on your website with his gmail credentials.

How to solve this ? So that logout works for both gmail and my site.

Comment: Show codes of controller and the library

Comment: That seems like it would only be an issue for someone using the same computer - I can't imagine other users are logged in to your gmail account. Irregardless, afaik there is no way for an external app to trigger a logout (not revoking tokens) for any service let alone Google - that would be a potential security issue on their end.

Comment: @Rajeevbbqq  
I used this library 
<div id="my-signin2"></div><script>
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
      console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }function onFailure(error) {
      console.log(error);
    } function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email','width': 240,'height': 50,'longtitle': true,'theme': 'dark', 'onsuccess': onSuccess, 'onfailure': onFailure  });}
  </script><script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>